# GetitembyId in list

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);

item["Title"] = TextBox_Name.Text;
item["ProductNumber"] = TextBox_ProdNum.Text;
item["ListPrice"] = TextBox_ListPrice.Text;
item["Color"] = TextBox_Color.Text;
item["More Info"] = TextBox_MoreInfo.Text;

item.SystemUpdate(false);
list.Update();
```

after writing following code in the list its only replace the first product not if i take more products in the list its only updates the one on place 1... can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 1):

`GetItemById` takes the Item whose Id is given in the function! so if you hardcode it to 1, it will always take the first List Item!

You should learn basics of SharePoint Object Model, if you want all the Items in the List simply use [SPList.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.items.aspx) property to get all the items in the List

You can use [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx) to get your desired items and use [List.GetItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.getitems.aspx)!

Once you run a query you will get [SPListItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.aspx) and you can use foreach with collection to update bulk items!

So it depends upon what you are trying to achieve, get hold of SP Object Model!

Comment: Just a warning: `SPList.Items` is executed exerytime it is evaluated [see here](http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/01/11/the-wrong-way-to-iterate-through-sharepoint-splist-items/). There are therefore some things to condider. Like: Prefer `SPList.AddItem` over `SPList.Items.Add`, store Items in a variable, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to iterate thought the `ID` collection which you want to update

Something like below

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];

int ids = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

for(int id in ids)
{
    SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(id);

    if(item != null)
    {
        item["Title"] = TextBox_Name.Text;
        item["ProductNumber"] = TextBox_ProdNum.Text;
        item["ListPrice"] = TextBox_ListPrice.Text;
        item["Color"] = TextBox_Color.Text;
        item["More Info"] = TextBox_MoreInfo.Text;

        item.SystemUpdate(false);
    }
}
```